# How to call Path.Combine from MSBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, path, msbuild

I have an `<Exec>` task that MSBuild runs whenever it builds my library. It looks like this:

```
<Exec Command="..\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.0.0\tools\xunit.console bin\$(Configuration)\Core.dll"/>
```

It seems to be working fine, however I'm worried that this may not work on Linux and OS X because it uses backslashes instead of the standard **`/`** for the directory separator. Is there a way to call Path.Combine from MSBuild so I can avoid this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert NAnt function "path::combine(path1, path2)" to MSBuild?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507215/how-to-convert-nant-function-pathcombinepath1-path2-to-msbuild)

Comment: So just use forward slashes, works on Windows as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use msbuild [property functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440(v=vs.120).aspx)

```
$([System.IO.Path]::Combine($(Path1),$(Path2)))
```